# Четные числа Фибоначчи. Проект Эйлера

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, числа-фибоначчи

В чем моя ошибка?
Я пытаюсь создать список из всех четных чисел Фибоначчи, но в моем списке присутствуют и нечетные числа.
Код:

```
numbers = [1, 2]

# Создаем ряд Фибоначчи
while numbers[-1] < 4000000:
    need = numbers[-2] + numbers[-1]
    numbers.append(need)

def filter():
    '''Эта функция оставляет только четные числа
    в списке numbers
    '''
    for num in numbers:
        if (num % 2) != 0:
            numbers.remove(num)
    print(numbers)
filter()
```

Comment: `print(numbers[1::3])`.

Comment: Yaant, спасибо за помощь!  
Все было намного проще, чем я думал.

Answer (score 2):

```
for num in numbers:
    if (num % 2) != 0:
        numbers.remove(num)
```

Вы удаляете элементы из списка во время итерирования по нему. Весь хвост сдвигается на одну позицию к началу при удалении, и Вы пропускаете элемент, идущий сразу за удаляемым.

Answer (score 1):

Все немного проще и менее ресурсоемко.

```
numbers = [1, 2]
odd_numbers=[]
while numbers[-1] < 4000:
    need = numbers[-2] + numbers[-1]
    numbers[-2],numbers[-1]=numbers[-1],need
    if (need % 2) == 0:
        odd_numbers.append(need)
print (odd_numbers)
```

Результат:

```
[8, 34, 144, 610, 2584]
```

Индексацию numbers оставил исключительно для вашего удобства, что-бы вас не запутать. На самом деле там, конечно, индексы  разумнее использовать 0 и 1.

Comment: Вроде в вопросе требовались наоборот, только четные числа (это банально каждое третье)?

Comment: Это просто поменять условие на if (need % 2) == 0:  Но если для ТС это непреодолимое препятствие для понимания, тоды  сейчас исправлю.